# Serialize Lucene's OpenBitSet 4.9.0 using Java

Tags: java, serialization, lucene, bitset

Using Lucene's OpenBitSet 4.9.0, I would like to serialize an object instance of the OpenBitSet-class. As the OpenBitSet class does not implement Serializable, I made my own class which extends OpenBitSet:

```
public class MyBitSet extends OpenBitSet implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

However, after deserialization, the original bits are not set. How to correctly implement a serializable OpenBitSet?

Quote from their website:

> It also allows one to efficiently implement alternate serialization or
>   interchange formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this like following:

1. Extend `OpenBitSet` to get access to `protected long[] bits` and `protected int wlen`. These are the only ones that provide state.
2. Implement `Externalizable`, and (de)serialize those two fields in `readExternal` and `writeExternal`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I ended with this solution:

```
public class MyBitSet extends OpenBitSet implements Externalizable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException
    {
        out.writeObject(bits);
        out.writeInt(wlen);     
    }

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        bits = (long[]) in.readObject();
        wlen = in.readInt();
    }
}
```